# Simple matplotlib animation

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I have an array with the coordinates and the velocities of a collection of particles, say x and v.

I can compute their evolution with a script I already wrote in Python, but I would like to visualize a simple animation of their motion in the x,v space

How can I simply update the plot at every iteration?

The code could roughly be written as

sets the initial x,v of every particle in an array

for k in range (1,N_iterations):

computes every particle's new position and velocity (the part I already wrote)

plots the updated array in the x,v space

waits an interval of time to be setted

the loop continues

Comment: you should be able to use [`matplotlib.animation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). [Here is a huge tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What is not working?